# Symfony 2.8 Can't create relations between two tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I have a problem with creating relations between two tables in Symfony (Doctrine).
I'm creating addressbook where I have Person Entity and I want to have relation wit Address Entity with relations OneToMany(One Person has many addresses).
When I run:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AdressBookBundle/Entiti/Address
```

I got error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                                 
  Namespace "AdressBookBundle\Entiti\Address" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

Below I put code with both Entities:

**Person:**

```
<?php

namespace AdressBookBundle\Entity;

use AdressBookBundle\Entity\Address;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Person
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdressBookBundle\Repository\PersonRepository")
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=500)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="person")
     */
    private $address;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set surname
     *
     * @param string $surname
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get surname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Person
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->address = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add address
     *
     * @param \AdressBookBundle\Entity\Address $address
     * @return Person
     */
    public function addAddress(\AdressBookBundle\Entity\Address $address)
    {
        $this->address[] = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove address
     *
     * @param \AdressBookBundle\Entity\Address $address
     */
    public function removeAddress(\AdressBookBundle\Entity\Address $address)
    {
        $this->address->removeElement($address);
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }
}
```

**Address:**

```
<?php

namespace AdressBookBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AdressBookBundle\Entity\Person;

/**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="address")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AdressBookBundle\Repository\AddressRepository")
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="text")
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="text")
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="house_number", type="integer")
     */
    private $houseNumber;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="house_unit_number", type="integer")
     */
    private $houseUnitNumber;

    /**
     * $@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $person;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * Set street
     *
     * @param string $street
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get street
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    /**
     * Set houseNumber
     *
     * @param integer $houseNumber
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setHouseNumber($houseNumber)
    {
        $this->houseNumber = $houseNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get houseNumber
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getHouseNumber()
    {
        return $this->houseNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Set houseUnitNumber
     *
     * @param integer $houseUnitNumber
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setHouseUnitNumber($houseUnitNumber)
    {
        $this->houseUnitNumber = $houseUnitNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get houseUnitNumber
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getHouseUnitNumber()
    {
        return $this->houseUnitNumber;
    }
}
```

Could You please explain me how it excactly works? 
As I understand I create relation by:

```
/**
     * $@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="person_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
```

And than neew column `person_id` is creating in Address table. Am I right?

Comment: Is `$` in `* $@ORM\ManyToOne` a typo? It shouldn't be there. The correct annotation should look like this `* @ORM\ManyToOne`

Comment: Can you spot an issue here with the word **Entity**?
`php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AdressBookBundle/Entiti/Address`

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your annotation:

```
$@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="address")
```

should be

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="address")
```

remove the *$* to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

remove the "$" from @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client").

@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client"). remove the "$"